# trouble importing python modules from other packages (pycharm gives unresolved reference)

Tags: python, import, package, importerror, pycharm

I don't know if pycharm is anything to do with the problem, or if it's me being noob.

Here is a screenshot of my folder layout and three code files:

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Pycharm on windows and "my_working_directory" is my working directory. You can see in the screenshot that in mod1.py "from package2.mod2" is underlined meaning "unresolved reference".

When I attempt to run mod1.py I get:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/play/my_working_directory/package1/mod1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/play/my_working_directory/package1/mod1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package2.mod2 import SomeClass
ImportError: No module named package2.mod2
```

When I run main.py I get:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/play/my_working_directory/main.py
hi
```

I don't understand why one works and not the other.

The main problem is that pycharm gives me no auto complete and from mod1 it can't detect package2. This is a huge problem because package1 is my view package, package2 is my models or utils or lib package (in a big model view controller). (example https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/web/handlers.py pycharm isn't detecting any of the from lib.? import ? statements. (giving unresolved reference).

Anyone know what's going on? Is this the best way of importing packages? Should I expect to be able to have autocomplete?

Should "my_working_directory" be made into a package by making another **init**.py file?

Comment: Think you need to add it to your python path. you can see package1 from main, but when importing mod1 you're in mod1 it cant see package2 from the import there because its in the parent folder, not in package1.

Comment: @GP89 "add it to your python path", what is "it"? C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\play\my_working_directory\ ? Also should it be my IDE's job to add this for me? or for all my projects should I be messing with my windows path settings under compter > properties > advanced settings > environment variables

Comment: Ah, I found under pycharm > settings > project structure, I had to change the project root from /play to /play/working_directory !!!

THanks a lot for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that C:/Users/Robert/PycharmProjects/play is not on your `%PYTHON_PATH%`

Comment: Hi Jakob, I think you could be onto something. I added print sys.path to mod1.py and main.py. Then I ran mod1.py and recorded the path. Then I ran main.py and recorded the path. The difference of the two path sets is: set(['C:\\Users\\Robert\\PycharmProjects\\play\\my_working_directory\\package1'])
set(['C:\\Users\\Robert\\PycharmProjects\\play\\my_working_directory'])

Comment: in mod1 I get
path1 = sys.path
for i in path1:
    if "play" in i:
        print i
C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\play\my_working_directory\package1
C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\play

Comment: in main.py I get:
for i in path2:
    if "play" in i:
        print i
C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\play\my_working_directory
C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\play

Comment: Right, I had /play as my pycharm root, when really I needed /play/my_working_directory as my project root.